# What is this USB mini-b like cable?

Tags: usb, cables

What is the cable on the left? It is supposed to be a cable for audio input for older gopros (in my case the 2014 hero), but my GoPro uses USB mini-b and this won't plug into it. I ordered one and thought it was defective, so the company sent me another one and the second one looks exactly the same, so now I don't know if they were both defective, or if this is some weird connector that I've never seen before.

The picture shows what I was sent (on the left) and a regular USB mini-b for comparison on the right.

[image]

Comment: It's a custom, to make you buy their (overpriced) cable.

Comment: it's a ripoff, that's what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this is called a 10 pin usb mini-b connector (the normal kind is 5 pin). Apparently some other GoPro models use it.